# SWIG C++ to C#: doesn't wrap enums with namespace correctly

Tags: c#, c++, enums, namespaces

I am trying to wrap C++ project to C# using SWIG (2.0.11 / 3.0.8) and I faced with problem with enums, here is simplified code of what I have:

**myEnum.hpp** - C++ side:

```
namespace NS1
{
    namespace NS2
    {
        enum myValue
        {
            VALUE_ONE = 1,
            VALUE_TWO = 2,
            VALUE_THREE = 3,
            VALUE_FOUR = 4
        };
    }
}

enum myEnum
{
    ONE = NS1::NS2::VALUE_ONE,
    TWO = NS1::NS2::VALUE_TWO,
    THREE = NS1::NS2::VALUE_THREE,
    FOUR = NS1::NS2::VALUE_FOUR
};
```

As a result of SWIG I got two C# files, one per enum.

**myValue.cs** - Looks correct, no issue here

```
public enum myValue {
  VALUE_ONE = 1,
  VALUE_TWO = 2,
  VALUE_THREE = 3,
  VALUE_FOUR = 4
}
```

and **myEnum.cs** - problematic one

```
public enum myEnum {
  ONE = NS1::NS2::VALUE_ONE,
  TWO = NS1::NS2::VALUE_TWO,
  THREE = NS1::NS2::VALUE_THREE,
  FOUR = NS1::NS2::VALUE_FOUR
}
```

As you can see values of second enum still have namespaces, that is fine for C++ but not C# as I am getting compilation which is :

> *myEnum.cs(13,17,13,19): error CS7000: Unexpected use of an aliased
>   name*

SWIG commands:

```
COMMAND "${SWIG_ROOT}/swig" -csharp -c++ -I${SWIG_INCLUDE_DIR} -o "CSharp_wrap.cxx" "CSharp.i"
COMMAND "${SWIG_ROOT}/swig" -csharp -c++ -I${SWIG_INCLUDE_DIR} -external-runtime "swigcsharprun.h"
```

So, what am I doing wrong? 
Thanks!